# Unit testing ONE piece of JSR 303 validator class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, bean-validation

I would like to unit test one validator class in Spring. There are 6 other existing validator classes but they don't have unit tests so I only want to test my validator class. 
My problem is that when I run my unit test (which tests only my class) "somehow" an other validator class is being tested... (it doesn't have unit test).

Is it possible that this is the default behaviour of the LocalValidatorFactoryBean to scan all the validator classes and to run their isValid method?
Can I specify the validator classes somehow that have to be tested? Like defining a ConstraintValidatorFactory?

Java test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-test-validator.xml"})
public class MyValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void testIsValid_true() {
        ...
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Record>> violations = validator.validate(data);
        ...
    }
}
```

application context XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" /> 
</beans>
```

Thanks,
V.

Comment: This isn't a unit test but an integration test. If you only want to test your validator then do only test your validator. Don't rely on infrastructure beans. You should be instantiating your validator, call the lifecycle methods and call the `isValid` method. Then you have a proper unit test.

Comment: Hi Deinum, thanks for the response! Yes, you are right, what I want is an integration test instead. I will do that you suggested but how should I configure my spring environment if I want to do I described above? Thanks, V.

Comment: This might probably help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062638/jsr-303-bean-validation-unit-testing-with-mockito-and-autowiring